# Ubuntu upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 disappears

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

It gives me the alert, and when I start it, sometimes it gets as far as the confirmation, but usually it just disappears after the user authentication. If I try it manually in the terminal, it gets to "Calculating Upgrade... Done" and then the next line says zero changes the end. It still gets regular updates, and the URLs are all pointing to Raring, so I don't know what it thinks is missing.

Answer (score 0):

My machine did this to me...I got the notification to upgrade to 13.10 and I clicked it on about 5 occasions and it did not do it.  A week later I got the prompt that it was ready to install and it did it...not sure what happened.

Now I have a new set of problems...my flash won't update in 13.10 and restart, shutdown, and logout don't work.